# Apache Velocity + Tomcat: Manually process templates within web-app

Tags: apache, tomcat, velocity, customtool

I am using Apache Tomcat with Velocity and VelocityViewServlet. I have created a custom tool with refference to ViewContext. It all works well.

The question is: what is best way to locate/load template and procces it with suplied parameters?

I have already absolute path to the file obtained via

```
((ViewContext)context).getRequest().getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

- Do I have to instantiate VelocityEngine? I suppose there is no global maintained by Velocity (VelocityViewServlet)
- Which (and how) of Velocity loaders is best to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points here:

- The VelocityViewServlet will instantiate itself a VelocityEngine. It's not global, it's one engine per ServletContext.
- The VelocityViewSerlet will locate itself the template that corresponds to the request URI using its default loader (WebappLoader), so you don't have to do it yourself either.
- The Velocity context your template will be evaluated with, will already be populated with all standard tools (for tools 2.0), among which $params which allows you to inspect HTTP parameters.
- I don't understand "a custom tool with refference to ViewContext": instead of using the ViewContext, you should add to your custom tool all the appropriate setters you need among the properties [listed here](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/creatingtools.html#Standard_Tool_Properties) (for instance, if you need access to the request, then you'll declare a "public setRequest(HttpServletRequest request)" method). Remember that from a bottom-up perspective, your tool must be only reachable via a key that you choose for it in your tools configuration file, and should not be aware of Velocity.
- I advise you to use VelocityTools 2.0, which is a more mature library than the 1.x.

Comment: Thx for response. I am already using 2.0. Refference to ViewContext is done via init(Object) method as described in Velocity guide. Atm I evaluate target template with Velocity.evaluate(vc, writer, "log", reader);

Comment: If you call Velocity.evaluate() yourself, then you don't need the VelocityViewServlet at all. That's why I think that there is something you are missing here. For the tool itself, the init() method will be called with a ViewContext, but my point here that it's a better practice to only declare setters for what you need (and the tools framework will call them). Plus, why would you want to locate a template from within a tool? The tool is meant to be instanciated and put in the context (either by you or by the tools framework), that's all...

Comment: All is handled by Velocity itself. Except one tool which actualy executes result of template as SQL and returns list of maps. Link (sql/myquery) is passed as argument along with other params (varargs). Its not ideal, but its required. So I am looking for the "purest" solution. Or just a tip. This is propably the most I can get so I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: You mean that some of your templates are templatized SQL queries, and that this tool is used to inject the results in your web templates? Maybe you should have a look at http://velosurf.sourceforge.net , with the disclaimer that I'm its author, it may respond to your need. Otherwise, I think you should have explained in your original question that you needed to evaluate a template from inside a tool, and why...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Its quite complex, and I oversimplified the question. Velosurf seems similar and You have some interesting ideas there. Thanks for your time.